# Modify File Upload script to Image CROP and thumb creation

Tags: php, file-upload

I would like to know how I can modify my file and data upload function, to crop the uploaded file and after that to create an additional thumb file with the same name in different directory but to put the file name only inside the database.

Here is my code so far I can upload the file and store the additional information:

public function fileupload() {

```
$file = rand(1000,100000)."-".$_FILES['file']['name'];
 $file_loc = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
 $file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
 $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
 $folder="uploads/";

 // new file size in KB
 $new_size = $file_size/1024;  
 // new file size in KB

 // make file name in lower case
 $new_file_name = strtolower($file);
 // make file name in lower case

 $final_file=str_replace(' ','-',$new_file_name);

 if(move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$folder.$final_file))
 {

    try {   
     $con = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
     $con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
     $sql = "INSERT INTO documents(topic, title, fecha, files, type, size, indicator) VALUES (:topic, :title, :fecha, :files, :type, :size, :indicator)";                                        
     $stmt = $con->prepare( $sql );                                          

$stmt->bindValue(':topic', $_POST['topic'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':title', $_POST['title'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':fecha', $_POST['fecha'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':files', $final_file, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':type', $file_type, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':size', $new_size, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':indicator', $_POST['indicator'], PDO::PARAM_STR);    
$stmt->execute(); 
header( 'Location: success_file.php?result=El File: <strong>"' .urlencode($_POST['topic']). '"</strong><br />fue agregado exitisamente!' ) ;


} catch (PDOException $e) { return $e->getMessage();
}

}
}
```

So can anybody tell me how to crop the uploaded file, and after this to create additional thumb file with different resolution ?